# Select values from mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

Please explain to me why it is not working.

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre,precio,presentacion FROM '$keywords'";
```

I used the next code and it worked but it's not what I need

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre,precio,presentacion FROM productos";
```

Comment: Can you provide info on "it worked, but it's not what I need"?  What was the result and what do you want the result to be?

Comment: remove the single quotes

Comment: ...also, what is the value of `$keywords`?  Is it an actual table?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be submitting a variable as a table name in any case

Answer (score 2):

You're using the incorrect quotes (Identifier Qualifiers) for your table, being single quotes.

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre,precio,presentacion FROM '$keywords'";
```

needs to read as

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre,precio,presentacion FROM `$keywords`";
```

While unknown as to which MySQL API you are using to connect with, using error checking on the query, would have thrown a syntax error.

Now, if your table name doesn't contain spaces or hyphens or a reserved word or anything else to give MySQL to complain about, you can just remove the quotes.

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre,precio,presentacion FROM $keywords";
```

For more information on Identifier Qualifiers, visit:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

---

**Error checking link references:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php - MySQL_*
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - MySQLi_*
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - PDO

---

**Footnotes:**

If you're assigning "productos" to the `$keywords` variable (which seems to be the case), such as:

```
$keywords = "productos";
```

then you can omit the quotes/ticks around that variable in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ticks from your table name. Hopefully `$keywords` is not a user supplied value or you will need to [sanitize it](http://bobby-tables.com/)

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre,precio,presentacion FROM $keywords";
```